# How to hook up a 14 year old receiver to a ASUS Xonar DGX

Tags: 5.1

I have a ASUS Xonar DGX sound card, and an older surround sound system that **currently I can only use for 2.0 sound, through a 1/8 to dual RCA** to receiver, but my receiver has a place for **digital in** (coax) (and component cables) (nothing else), so I'm wondering if I can make it support 5.1 that the receiver has.

PC: https://pcpartpicker.com/user/RacerD123/saved/#view=GWhZxr (except the 16 gb of RAM)

Sound Card: www asus.com/us/Essence_HiFi_Audio/Xonar_DGX/ (on win10 with UNi Xonar)

Receiver: Pioneer DVD/CD Receiver XV-HTD520

[picture of back](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz8cInpDMhqtTmpVNTZISE5tYjA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Photos of the back panels would help a lot, as would a link or mention of what the reciever model is. If I was asking the question, I'd also include a link to the product page of the sound card. Don't forget, not everyone has the same setup you do, but if they do, knowing what all the gear in play is would be good.

Comment: "component" cables? You mean component video, or...? If you mean discreet audio channel inputs, the Xonar probably uses the standard colours - Green for L/R, Black for Centre/Sub & Orange for Rear L/R. You need 3 mini-jack to [presumably] RCA cables

Comment: well my receiver doesn't have multi channel input.